# Changing Font Size of QGIS Profile Tool Plugin

Tags: qgis, elevation, profile

I have used this plugin often in the past but always wished to enlarge the font size on the graph scale, and make it darker.

Does anyone know how to tweak the code to do this or suggest another way in GQIS to get elevation profiles that are legible?

I have 50 to output so it has to be simple to do.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the default visualisation from the tool, go to the Table tab and copy the table to Excel and graph it there.

[image]

This has the benefit of saving off your results, a lot more flexibility in the visualisation, you can standardise the scales across profiles, etc.